# Yii2. Белый экран после переноса на сервер

Tags: php, yii2, iis, iis-10

После переноса файлов приложения с первоисточника (IIS 10) на сервер LAMP столкнулся с тем, что вместо любой из страниц в браузере белый экран.

Отображение ошибок в PHP включено, но не помогает т.к. в браузере не отображается вообще ничего.

Если на тот же хост установить "чистый" Yii2 из дистрибутива, всё работает как положено. Но, такой вариант по понятным причинам меня не устраивает.

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

1. Посмотрите логи в папке Yii 2 `runtime/logs`.
2. Проверьте права доступа ([`chmod`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)) на основные папки Yii 2: **`runtime`, `web/assets`**.

Comment: В логах информация только до переноса на хост. После переноса ничего не добавлялось (видимо падает раньше логирования). На папки полный доступ, но и это проблему не решило. увы...

Comment: Так может, сервер не понимает входную точку? Он точно указывает `DOCUMENT_ROOT` в `web`?

Comment: С сервером проблем нет. Если бы был неправильный DocumentRoot эта ошибка наверняка бы повторялась и на фреймворке из дистрибутива.

Comment: Значит это проблема в самом приложении.

Comment: Проблема оказалась даже не в самом приложении, а в том, о чём никто даже не мог подумать (см. мой ответ на вопрос).

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался самостоятельно.

Проблема оказалась в том, что при архивации на первоисточнике (IIS 10) перед переносом был повреждён ряд жизненно важных файлов фреймворка. В результате на рабочем сервере были развёрнуты изначально повреждённые файлы со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Конечно, никто и подумать не мог, что дело именно в этом (пока не дошло до ревизии файлов приложения).

Проблема была решена путём выполнения повторной архивации для переноса при остановленном IIS.